# Url Rewrite weird url matching behaviour

Tags: .net, regex, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

Ok so I have recently been using IIS Url Rewrite and have found it great, however i have come across some confusing behaviour.

First let me tell you what i was trying to accomplish:

```
/{word1}/{id}-{word2}

301 to

/{newWord1}/{id}-{word2}
```

Now let me show you the rule I first tried for this:

```
        <rule name="Hub Page Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="/service/([0-9]+)\-([^/]+/?)$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/hubs/{R:1}-{R:2}" />
        </rule>
```

As you can see i'm matching only a particular structure of URL then redirect to a custom url using some capture groups from the match. This only worked for the following structure (Example Below):

```
/service/1460-berkshire
```

It did not work when a slash was added at the end of it? However when I changed the rule to the below:

```
        <rule name="Hub Page Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="/service/([0-9]+)\-([^/]+/?)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/hubs/{C:1}-{C:2}" />
        </rule>
```

All worked fine? All I did was instead of matching only particular urls i'm matching any, then matching on that via a condition. The condition pattern is the same pattern that I was originally using to match against the URL.

Why didn't my first rule completely work?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is a bit of inconsistency between {URL} and the Match URL.
The reason it is failing for your is that when you are requesting a "root URI", the leading slash "/" in the match URL attribute, it is not included, so for example your request to /service/1460-berkshire, sends RequestURL="service/1460-berkshire", and so that does not match due to the leading "/" in your regex. If you always expect that to be at the root, then the best rule (performance and clarity) would be:

```
<rule name="Hub Page Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^service/([0-9]+)\-([^/]+/?)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/hubs/{R:1}-{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

that way you are specifying at the root, and will match that faster and only that URL.

In your second rule, it is passed ExpandedInput="/service/1460-berkshire" so then the condition actually matches it.

My recommendation for people is to use Failed Request Tracing to see why URL Rewrite rules match or not, it is the best source to see exactly why it works or not and remove most of the guessing work.

See: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response this was very helpful! However i think there has been some confusion. When i mentioned that my first rule only worked without the slash i didn't mean the leading one i meant the trailing one. The rule worked with '/service/1460-berkshire' but not '/service/1460-berkshire/'. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other rule before it? In my machine I can see that URL working fine, but the rule I shared is the only rule I have at this point. I would enable Failed Request Trace as in the article and see why that might not be matching. It might be another rule that is before with stopProcessing=true which prevents it from even running.

Comment: Ill enable Failed Request Trace see if I can find anything out thanks for your help